# Flutter: How to avoid flutter to automatically change text color

Tags: dart, flutter

If I use a lighter color as primary color in flutter all text automatically goes black. If I choose an dark primary color all text in the app goes white.

I'm aware they chose a color that fits good because the color might be to dark or to light for the text color which might be annoying for the eye, but I would stil like to avoid this behavior.

I know that I can go thru all the textthemes and try to set them all but I would like to avoid that to if possible since it's hard to find all and set them correctly.

```
    child: MaterialApp(
    title: 'Test App',
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    theme: ThemeData(
      brightness: Brightness.light,
      primaryColor: Colors.teal[200], // All text is black
      primaryColor: Colors.teal[800], // ALL text is white

    ),
```

**Question: How do I avoid this automatic color change depending on my primary color and can I just chose one or another text color at one place?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add

```
primaryTextTheme: Typography().black, // or white
```

to the ThemeData

Comment: Thanks, I will accept this since it did affect all the text. However there are more colors than just text that is affected with this so my problem still remains actually.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `primaryTextTheme`:

```
ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Colors.teal[200],
    primaryTextTheme: TextTheme(
      title: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      subHead: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      body1: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      // etc...
    ),
),
```

Comment: Ye I played around with this one before but was hard trying to set all the values correctly in there. Since actually it's not only text it's other accent colors aswell that get affected